# myaccount:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: signature is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the color of "Name" onclick but getting an error as not defined! Is there any mistake that I can't see it.
Thanks, in advance.

HTML CODE as Belowl

```
<p id="text"> Name </p>
 <div>
      <select name="color" id="change" onchange="signature()">
        <option value="black" selected>Black</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

Javascript Code as Bellow

```
function signature(){         
   var color = $('#change').val();  
   $("#text").css("color", color);     
}
```

Comment: See the error in the browser's console `unexpected token {`. You need to change `signature()` to `function signature()`. [Functions 101](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Comment: Add Jquery (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js)

Comment: Did you stick the function inside of a document.ready block?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `function` key word:

```js
function signature(){
      let color = $('#change').val()
      $("#text").css("color", color);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text"><br> Name </p>

<div>
     <select name="color" id="change" onchange="signature()">
    <option value="black" selected>Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

And if you want to do it without jQuery:

```js
function signature(){
      let color = document.getElementById('change').value
      document.getElementById("text").style.color = color;
 }
```

```html
<p id="text"><br> Name </p>

<div>
     <select name="color" id="change" onchange="signature()">
    <option value="black" selected>Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

Comment: I tried that but it gives an error, also I used the same format of not writing function word before actual function and it works.. Following is the error while using function word---> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

Comment: @RonKu Did you include jQuery?  Your code is using jQuery (hence the $).